# JBoss - Can it be used as a HTTP server?

Tags: java, apache, jboss, apache2, jboss7.x

I'm trying to have a home web hosting and i'm wondering if JBoss can be used as a HTTP server - just like Apache HTTP server.

If i bring up JBoss using port 80, will an outside request directing to my PC IP address, it will serve a HTTP request?

I tried and it didn't work (no surprise).

Any opinion?

With Apache HTTP server, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ways to have JBoss serve requests over port 80, however, you really **should never do that**. Because doing so will require some security compromises such as running jboss as root or hack/modify the port restrictions on the OS level.

What you want to is install an apache web server (jboss web server has apache web server or you can download it of the apache site) and then have a load balancer such as `mod-jk` or `mod-cluster` forward the requests to JBoss worker nodes. Ideally your apache web server and jboss servers should be located in 2 separate host servers (virtual or physical).

So your set up would be like: `httpd (apache serving static contents such as images, static html)->mod-jk->JBoss AS7 (serving dynamic contents such as JSPs, servlets, etc)` .

Comment: That confirms my thoughts. Thanks!!